# ASP.NET MVC 4 Website Speed Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, newrelic

We've just finished building a website for a customer in MVC 4, the site is deployed and online, however the client is now complaining of seriously slow load times. We are unable to replicate the issue viewing the very same website on our machines.

To start investigating the issue we have hooked up New Relic to our server and are monitoring the app, and here's what we're seeing:

[image]

There is a massive 57,900 ms response time on the WebTransaction, problem is we have no idea what exactly this web transaction is nor how to go about resolving it.

Has anyone ever seen this? How can we go about resolving this massive load time?

Thanks,

Comment: Most of time having "Transaction" and "Slow" in the same sentence does not surprises me...

Comment: Do you call CRM server from your app?

Comment: When I first deployed my app I was having issues with it loading the first time every `n` minutes. The problem was the time IIS took to spin up the app pool after recycling it. We fixed the issue by setting the recycle time to ~24 hours.

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc, Thanks for the suggestion, we don't call CRM servers from within the app.

Comment: @Billdr, thanks the app pool recycling settings we're set to every 1740 minutes (default). I've changed this to a fixed time of 05:00 and 00:00 to see if that affects anything..

Comment: What is your IIS timeout duration?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Some more details in the question and an answer might be useful for others.

Comment: @LJNielsenDk unfortunately we never did manage to iron out what was happening with this issue. We tried adjusting the IIS timeout duration, app pool settings to no avail. I'm sorry I couldn't help you further.

Comment: WebTransaction is term used by NewRelic. Please contact them for help. They seem to provide decent level of support. I found two following threads that talk about WebTransaction and it taking long time. Granted they are for [WordPress/PHP](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/high-percentage-of-time-spent-in-webtransaction-what-should-i-look-for/11897) and [Python](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/very-high-reported-webtransaction-time/3584). Nonetheless, they are good reads. CRM Details is your clue. Do you have any NuGet packages in your project relating to Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to optimize a mvc site 
most common problem is Variable of type list.
when we are accessing the data we are using List of data then we perform some operations and then sending to controller.
Instead of doing this ,If we will use Queryable type data then operation then sending data to controller then it will be faster then previous.